# Stopping unordered list being taller than parent div with padding

Tags: css

I have a unordered list that is as tall as the page. I don't want it flush with the sides of the div so I added padding. Except now it is overflowing. How can I make the list be as tall as it's parent minus the padding?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Clear any defaults on the ul */
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

/* Make a container that fills the entire screen */
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: hotpink;
}

/* Left hand 200px wide menu */
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: blanchedalmond;
}

/* Fill the remaining width of the screen. */
.content {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: mistyrose;
}

/* 200px wide that shouldn't be taller than it's container */
.list {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid orchid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8A2un/

Comment: Add `box-sizing` to `.content` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `box-sizing: border-box` to `.content`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8A2un/1/

Comment: Seems @Nick_R beat me to it... :)

Comment: Aha, I thought `border-box` only applied to to the border, I didn't realise it made the padding happen inside the box too.